# Meteor: Changing a subtemplate without changing parent template

Tags: javascript, meteor

If I have the following template structure

```
 <template name="A">
            {{> B}}
            {{> C}}
    </template>
```

How can I have C update when it changes without having Template A re-render?

I've tried `{{#isolate}}{{> C}}{{/isolate}}` but this doesn't work and using a constant region isn't quite right either as this isn't a constant region.

Comment: It should work. And it works in my test. Can you add more code? Maybe something else is causing A to re-render? How do you keep-track when A re-renders?

Answer (score 1):

As of Meteor 0.7.0.1, re-rendering a sub-template causes the parent to re-render but not *sibling* templates.  Isolate works the same way.

I put together a simple example of this that you can play with here:

https://github.com/alanning/meteor-subtemplate-isolate-test

Keep in mind that this behavior may change with the upcoming release of Meteor UI in preparation for Meteor 1.0.