# Meteor: Changing a subtemplate without re-rendering parent template

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

According to Meteor's documentation, changing things inside #isolate block will not cause the parent template to re-render, but I encounter different behavior for the following example, where both 'hello' and 'a' re-renders when I change 'title':

```
<head>
  <title>testing</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
{{#isolate}}
  {{> a}}
{{/isolate}}

{{#isolate}}
  {{> b}}
{{/isolate}}

</template>

<template name='a'>
 a: {{title}}
</template>

<template name='b'>
 b: {{desc}}
</template>
```

Here is the javascript

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.hello.rendered = function () {
    console.log('hello')
  };

  Template.a.rendered = function () {
    console.log('a')
  };

  Template.b.rendered = function () {
    console.log('b')
  };

  Handlebars.registerHelper('title', function() {
    return Session.get('title');
  });

  Handlebars.registerHelper('desc', function() {
    return Session.get('desc');
  });

}
```

Am I misinterpreting something? I saw a similar but unanswered question here:
[Meteor: Changing a subtemplate without changing parent template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005848/meteor-changing-a-subtemplate-without-changing-parent-template)

Comment: Note that `{{#isolate}}` is [no longer](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#no-more-constant-isolate-or-preserve) part of [Spacebars](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the parent template would be re-rendered because it has to be redrawn.

While only the section inside the `{{#isolate}}` bit would have changed (containing template a), The template `hello` would have changed, this is why re-rendered is called.

Every time a template's html is changed by the Spark rendering engine (the current version that powers meteor's template system), `.rendered()` would be called.

In the new rendering engine, Shark, `.rendered()` would only be called once, on the initial load. This might be more to what you're looking for but its still in a preview release

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the new engine. https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/New-Template-Engine-Preview#fine-grained-updates-that-play-nicely-with-jquery